# no sé me ocurre como definir el concepto de derecha e izquierda

Tags: python, string

tengo que realizar un ejercicio el cuál la letra dice lo siguiente:
ea una cadena de caracteres c. Decimos que una vocal v dentro de c está en equilibrio si la cantidad de vocales a la izquierda de v es igual a la cantidad de vocales a la derecha (podrían ser cero vocales).

Implementar una función en Python que dado un string retorne la ubicación  en donde se encuentra la vocal en equilibro (si es que la hay); si no tiene vocal en equilibrio debe retornar -1 (los strings con un número par de vocales no tiene vocal en equilibrio). Es claro que una cadena tiene una sola vocal en equilibrio o ninguna.

La función debe definirse con el nombre EnQuilibrio(cadena). Tenga en cuenta que se considerarán como vocales incluso las vocales mayúsculas y las acentuadas (tanto mayúsculas como minúsculas).

Ejemplos:

"Programación" está en equilibrio (la vocal en equilibrio es la segunda "a", pues tiene 2 vocales antes y dos vocales después), por lo tanto la función debería devolver 7 (que es la posición dentro del string de la vocal en equilibrio)
"perro" no tiene vocal en equilibrio, por lo tanto retornará -1
"pez" tiene a la "e" en quilibrio porque no hay ninguna tanto a izquierda como a derecha, por lo tanto  retornará 1 (posición de la vocal "e"
"Ágora" está en equilibrio (no tar de que se debe contemplar a las vocales acentuadas y mayúsculas).
Ayuda: defina una función EsVocal(v) que retorne True si v es una de las vocales consideradas (minúscula, mayúscula, o combinación con acento). Considere además hacer una función que cuente la cantidad de vocales que tiene un string.

realice las funciones consideradas, pero no se me ocurre como implementar el concepto de derecha e izquierda, lo pensé por bastante tiempo pero no llegué a una solución, lo único que entendí es que si la cantidad de vocales de una palabra es par, esta no tiene vocal en equilibrio.
hasta ahora mi código es este:

```
def esvocal(string):
    vocales="a,e,i,o,u,á,é,í,ó,ú"
    cadena=string.lower()
    if cadena in vocales:
        return True
    else:
        return False
print(esvocal("á"))

def cantidadvocales(string):
    vocales="a,e,i,o,u,á,é,í,ó,ú"
    cadena=string.lower()
    cantidadvocales=0
    for elem in cadena:
        if elem in cadena and elem in vocales:
            cantidadvocales=cantidadvocales+1
    return cantidadvocales


    def equilibrio(string):
        vocales=cantidadvocales(string)
        vocal=esvocal(string)
        for i in range(len(string)):
            if vocales %2==0:
                return -1
            else:
                if i==vocal and vocales
    
    
    
    
    
    print(equilibrio("Programación"))
```

Comment: puedes usar *slicing* para obtener los caracteres a la derecha e izquierda según un caracter. Ejemplo, si quieremos obtener los carcteres a la derecha e izquierda de x `cadena = "aexio"` hacemoc `izq = cadena[: cadena.find("x")]; der = cadena[cadena.find("x")+1: ]`. O incluso puedes hacer un `split`, pero todo depende de la entrada

Comment: entendí, el tema es que al find le tengo que poner un caracter en específico no?, no puedo iterar con un for i in range y hacer el find de i

Comment: y que piensas hacer con el for? si iteras en el rango de la cadena entonces facilmente puedes hacer `cadena[i]` y obtienes el caracter.

Comment: bien, entendí itero y hago cadena[i] y ahí tendría que comparar si cadena de i tiene la misma cantidad de vocales con la función que ya tengo creada a la izquierda y a la derecha

Comment: exacto.........

Answer (score 0):

La implementación puede ser mucho más sencilla de lo que se enuncia. Primero se recorre toda la cadena buscando las vocales. Los índices de esas vocales se guardan en una lista `eq`.

Finalmente, si la cantidad de vocales `len(eq)` es impar se retorna el índice que está en el medio de la lista `eq`, o sea: `eq[len(eq)//2]`, de lo contrario se retorna `-1`.

```py
def equilibrio(cadena):
    vocals = 'a,e,i,o,u,á,é,í,ó,ú'
    eq = [k for k,c in enumerate(cadena) if c.lower() in vocals]
    return eq[len(eq)//2] if (len(eq) % 2) else -1
```

No se indica qué pasa si la cadena tiene un única vocal y está al inicio o al final. Este código devolverá `0` o `len(cadena)-1` en el caso respectivo. Si no quieres ese comportamiento tendrás que hacer esa evaluación.

Haciendo pruebas:

```py
print(equilibrio('Programación')) # 7
print(equilibrio('perro')) # -1
print(equilibrio('pez')) # 1
print(equilibrio('Ágora')) # 2
```